# script out of range error help needed

Tags: excel, vba

I have this snip of code that will not populate worksheet names for printing in a PDF.  I get a subscript out of range compiling error.  Any ideas?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Macros").Select

Dim strPath As String, strFileName As String
Dim i As Integer, y As Integer, x As Integer
Dim WkstNames() As Variant
Dim iCount As Integer, iWkstCount As Integer
Dim printrange As Range
Set printrange = Range("P222:P248")
Dim p() As Variant

iCount = 1
iWkstCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

ReDim WkstNames(1 To iWkstCount)
ReDim p(1 To 27)

For y = 1 To iWkstCount
    For x = 1 To 27
    printrange.Rows(p(x)).Select
    If ActiveCell = "True" Then WkstNames(y) = Sheets(iCount).Name
    iCount = iCount + 1
    Next x
Next y

Sheets(WkstNames).Select ' error occurs here
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is pretty simple actually. You are redimming your array in the beginning and your line `WkstNames(y) = Sheets(iCount).Name` is not executing and hence you are getting at least one blank value in the array.

Try and loop through the array after it is created. Use this code

```
For i = LBound(WkstNames) To UBound(WkstNames)
    Debug.Print WkstNames(i)
Next i
Worksheets(WkstNames).Select
```

You will notice at least one value is blank and hence Excel cannot find the sheet.

A working example would be something like

```
Dim WkstNames(1 To 2) As String
WkstNames(1) = "Sheet1"
WkstNames(2) = "Sheet2"
Worksheets(WkstNames).Select
```

**Example (Followup from comments)**

This is just an example to show how you can select sheet(s) without declaring an array beforehand.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ar
    Dim wsName As String, sDelim As String

    sDelim = "|"

    With ThisWorkbook
        For i = 1 To .Sheets.Count
            If .Sheets(i).Name Like "Sheet*" Then
                If wsName = "" Then
                    wsName = .Sheets(i).Name
                Else
                    wsName = wsName & sDelim & .Sheets(i).Name
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        If InStr(1, wsName, sDelim) Then
            Ar = Split(wsName, sDelim)
        Else
            Ar = wsName
        End If

        .Sheets(Ar).Select
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: So i would have to name all 27 sheets with if then statements in the working example?  Surely there is an easier way rather manually doing it this way?

Comment: Yes there is a simpler way rather than dimming the array before hand. Updated the post